# Which changes are required to autostart youtube video in default embed code?

Tags: youtube, embed

What changes are required in youtube default embed code to let videos auto start on the web pages on-load?

https://www.youtube.com/embed/ngM_8pqGjmA?autoplay=1

```
<div width="100%" align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ngM_8pqGjmA?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Output is normal, embedded but not auto starting. Video is embedded here on Google sites based website https://www.ibpspoexam.com/

Answer (score 3):

Today you'll need to use `?autoplay=1&mute=1` since most browsers have disabled auto starting videos with audio. `start=2` is most likely not needed.

Answer (score 1):

That video is set to `start` parameter at 0:02 as follows:

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/ngM_8pqGjmA?autoplay=1;start=2

By adding the `start` paarmeter in your code, the video will autoplay.

Here is the code - with the `start` parameter added:

```
<div width="100%" align="center"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ngM_8pqGjmA?autoplay=1;start=2" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: I've updated the same code on this url https://www.ibpspoexam.com but it's not working.

Comment: @PuneetpalSingh strange, I can see the autoplay correctly in Google Chrome (*in normal and incognito mode* - Version 76.0.3809.100 (Build oficial) (32 bits)). Do you have the developer tools open while you're on that website?, if so, close it. Which browser you're checking this?